# получение связей через аннотации ManyToMany

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2, entity, relation

есть классы

User

```
namespace FOS\UserBundle\Model\User;
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
```

Product

```
namespace Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product;
class Product {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
```

FavoriteProduct

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity\FavoriteProduct;
class FavoriteProduct {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;
```

хочу в продукте получить связь для этого пользователя

переопределяю  Product

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity\Product;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product as BaseProduct;
class Product extends  BaseProduct{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sylius\Component\Core\Model\User")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="favorite_product",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
    private $favorites;
```

В этом случае я получаю всех пользователей с у которых в закладках тот товар. Могу ли я получить связь именно текущего пользователя? если да то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если говорить про предметную область, то вы не корректно выбрали связи.
Так товар ничего не должен знать о пользователе, а вот пользователь может иметь товары в избранном.

Соответственно у нас должна быть связь User <--> Favorite --> Product.

Второй момент, если Favorite не имеет дополнительных свойства кроме самих связей, то выделять отдельный класс является избыточным решением.
Но если вы хотите например хранить дату добавления в избранное, или например позицию в избранном, тогда класс нужен.

Для дальнейшего решения, допустим, что вам нужен дополнительный класс и вы планируете хранить какие-то свойства относящиеся к избранному.

В этом случае класс пользователя должен быть представлен как:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FavoriteProduct", mappedBy="user")
     */
    property $favoriteProducts;

    public function getFavoriteProducts()
    {
        return $this->favoriteProducts ?: new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Тогда связующий класс между пользователем и продуктом, в соответсвии со [сноской в документации](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional), будет представлен:

```
 // src/AppBundle/Entity/FavoriteProduct.php

class FavoriteProduct
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="favoriteProducts")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     */
    protected $product;
}
```

В шаблоне проверку можно осуществлять как:

```
{% if app.user.favoriteProducts.contains(product) %}...{% endif %}
```

Comment: спасибо за то что указали на мои ошибки, и достаточно подробно описали Ваше решение

Answer (score 0):

Если кому интересно поборол это так
**Product**

```
public function itsUserFavorite($id)
{
    if($this->favorite->count()) {
        foreach ($this->favorites as $favorite) {
            if ($favorite->getId() == $id) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

в представлении

```
  user.itsUserFavorite(product.id)
```

вопрос остается открытым. Так как мое решение не считаю хорошим. Ждем эспертов